# chrome extension: refuse header "date" in ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, http-headers, google-chrome-extension

I have a javascript code to be used for api (ajax) and I need to send header "date" to api-server (required header), but chrome tells me 'refused to set unsafe header "Date" ' and I get response from api-server like "missing required http date header".

I'm using jquery.

code sample:

```
var d = new Date();
var headers = {};
headers["Date"] = d.toUTCString();
jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<some HTTPS url>'
            type: "get",
            crossDomain: true,
            headers: headers,
            ....

})
```

the same code works fine in firefox.
does anybody have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah Chrome must refuse your request because the standard says:

> Terminate these steps if header is a  match for one of the following headers:
> [...]
>
> - Date

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Since you are sending a XHR request it MUST be terminated according to the standard when you set a whole list of prohibited headers:

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-setrequestheader-method

You'll need to proxy through your originating url or some other work around.

Answer (score 0):

Its lame because if you use Firefox and the RestClient you can do it. But you can't if you use Chrome and the "Advanced Rest Client"