# Include date field in to the header requests Web Api

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

Is it possible to enable date field in to http requests? I have an object on my client side:

```
let init = {
    method: typeof method === 'string' ? method : 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Language': getLanguage()
    }
```

The problem is I adding `'Date' : new Date()` to the header server doesn't get any key-value pair (via WebApi). Also in network section of browser there is no above field. I've read some information this field is closed for any manipulation. As I understand I need to enable it for including not by hands. So, how can I tell to browser to send it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible once the browser is supposed to set the header, not you. If you were able to set the header, that would defeat the purpose of the security feature.

Also, [if you try to force it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6974039/1269558) you'll probably get the error:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Date"
```

Once we try the request without setting this header, we'll see that the browser doesn't set it for you (only for `response` object, which is easier to manipulate).

**Some alternatives:**

- [Create custom headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404734/how-to-add-and-get-header-values-in-webapi) and receive their values at the WebApi
- Or even pass the value as a parameter (body POST, e.g)